# Translucent navigation bar overrides in pushed view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, transition

I have a translucent navigation bar with blurred content.

I want to push a new view controller with another translucent navigation bar but no content to blur (yet), so I do a simple `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`.

However, during transition the old navigation bar overrides the new one for a split second, then it goes back to normal. 
How to avoid this and achieve a smooth transition?

I tried playing with `isTranslucent` property of navigation bar inside `viewWillAppear` but no luck.

Here's a gif to understand the problem:

[image]

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483

Comment: I have tried overriding `isViewLoaded` but I realised I actually don't have any code for updating the navigation bar, since it's the same as the previous view controller. I have tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511088/navigationbar-coloring-in-viewwillappear-happens-too-late-in-ios-10/39518148#39518148) too but I don't know what to put in there to update the navigation bar appearance.

Comment: Have the same problem, and can't find the solution. Have you found it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the navigation bar translucent while and after transition, check the "Under Top Bars" property in the inspector.
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. How can i do this in code? I don't use storyboards