# Delay in changing navigationBar.barTintColor in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers in a navigation controller. I'm trying to change the tint color of the navigation bar for each view controller.

I'm using the following code to accomplish this:

FirstVC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .yandasRed
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

SecondVC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

The transition between FirstVC to SecondVC is seemless, and looks great. However when I go back to the FirstVC from the SecondVC, there is a delay in changing the navigation bar tint color. About 1/2 a second.

Why is this? I was under the impression that all code inside viewWillAppear is executed before the view controller is loaded.

Comment: Tried the code in the linked question. It crashes the app immediately on loading. I have no understading of how isViewLoaded works, so possibly the code is incomplete?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40377268/5561496), you can implement:

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)
    // Setup your navigation bar
}
```

I believe this will eliminate the delay.