# How to get rid of the delay of changing the color of the Navigation Bar when moving to the previous screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

After tap on back(NavBar) I see a delay(1.5 s). I don't understand why.

Comment: Try to use `viewDidDisappear` instead of `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: I try - nothing changes

Comment: you need to check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511088/navigationbar-coloring-in-viewwillappear-happens-too-late-in-ios-10/40377268#40377268

Answer (score 0):

Func willMove from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621381-willmove) help me.